# method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 61, g: 91, b: 151)
    }

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent

    }
}

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
```

whenever i change

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

i get threaded error that wouldn't let my simulator load

Comment: Why do you want to use preferredStatusBarStyle as a property?

Comment: Ah right, maybe I misunderstood your question. So you already tried the property approach but still get some error?

Answer (score 1):

`preferredStatusBarStyle` is a computed property, not a function as stated in your question.

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Here's how it should be:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: It's not just a matter of replacing `func` with `var`. You also need to remove the parameter list (`()`), and change the `->` to `:`

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's a var, not a func. Try this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `preferredStatusBarStyle` is a property, not a function. Instead of

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .lightContent
}
```

use

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked.